# Why GPU slower than CPU in my case?

Tags: tensorflow

What my code does is to fitting such a function: y = x*0.1+0.3

Here is my code:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    # create data
    x_data = tf.random_uniform(shape=[100], minval=0, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32, seed=1)

    y_data = x_data*0.1 + 0.3

    ## create tensorflow structure start ###
    Weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
    y = Weights*x_data + biases
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y-y_data))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
    train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
### create tensorflow structure end ###
    sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
    # tf.initialize_all_variables() no long valid from
    # 2017-03-02 if using tensorflow >= 0.12
    if int((tf.__version__).split('.')[1]) < 12 and int((tf.__version__).split('.')[0]) < 1:
        init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    else:
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    for step in range(200000):
        sess.run(train)
        if step % 200 == 0:
            print(step, sess.run(Weights), sess.run(biases))
```

I've read this article:
https://codedump.io/share/1Q5QpLYsQ3hD/1/tensorflow-matmul-calculations-on-gpu-are-slower-than-on-cpu

I know datas generated by CPU are stored in RAM.If we use GPU to calculate,it 
takes extra tansfer time.How sholud I do to make my codes run faster with GPU?To make GPU run faster than CPU.

Comment: Try with larger weight matrixs (you only have one value, so you have nothing to parallelize here! ) To really use your gpu, you have to have bigger calculs to make, otherwise you just get the overhead of transfering to GPU...

Comment: @ArnaudDeBroissia Ok,thanks!

Comment: @user1735003 thanks!